# Prevent the second of two bound events to a radio input from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following piece of code:

```html
<form [attributes]>
  <input class="bound" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="1" id="Radio1" />
  <label for="Radio1">One</label>

  <input class="bound" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="2" id="Radio2" />
  <label for="Radio2">Two</label>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now, this stuff gets prepopulated - so, if a user lands on this page - a radio button may be pre-selected. But I want the event handler to fire even if the radio button is clicked, so I am using two `$.on()` using 'click' and 'change':

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.bound', function(event) {

      console.log( 'called click handler' );
      event.stopPropagation();

    });
    $(document.body).on('change', '.bound', function(event) {

      console.log( 'called change handler' );
      event.stopPropagation();

    });

  });
</script>
```

When you click on a radio button, it fires both events. I would like for only one event to get fired. Is there a possible/feasible way to accomplish this? I thought `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` would work, but it didn't seem to.

Comment: Why do you need 2 event handlers?

Comment: Hey - I am not positive that I do, honestly. I just wanted an event to fire if someone clicked a radio button that was 'pre-selected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need 2 event handlers.

```
$(function () {
    $(document.body).on('change', '.bound', function (event) {
        console.log('called change handler');
    });
    // fire it for pre-selected
    $('.bound:checked').change();
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/44M6Z/)***

​

Comment: This does not work, for the reasons I explained above - if a radio button is already 'selected', clicking it will not fire the `change` event since the value remains unchanged.

Comment: Why not? because I want to perform an animation when they do so.

Comment: If the user changes the selection using the cursors, will that still fire? Part of me thinks it will, just not certain.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use event.stopImmediatePropagation()

This will tell jQuery to not fire any remaining subscribers.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/